# how to apply Condition on Theme for web view

Tags: android

I have created two themes in my application themeA and themeB i want to check which theme is being used, something like the following code:

```
if( themeA ...)
{
    webview.setBackgroundcolor(color.black);
    String str1 = "<font color='white'>" + getDescription + "</font>";
}
else
{
    webview.setBackgroundcolor(color.white);
    String str1="<font color='black '>" + getDescription + "</font>";
}
```

Is it possible to check which `Theme` is currently being used?